# convert strategy to study pinescript

Tags: pine-script

is it possibel to make this to a study insted so there can be set alarms for buy and stop

im no coder some im kind off lost here

if any can help im willing to cast some coin after it

```
 if long
    strategy.entry("L_1", strategy.long, when=ACT_BT and testPeriod)
   
if short
    strategy.entry("S_1", strategy.short, when=ACT_BT and testPeriod)
  

curProfitInPts() =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        (high - strategy.position_avg_price) / syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        (strategy.position_avg_price - low) / syminfo.mintick
    else
        0
        
calcStopLossPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.position_avg_price + OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else
        na
        
calcProfitTrgtPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    calcStopLossPrice(-OffsetPts)

getCurrentStage() =>
    var stage = 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0 
        stage := 0
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
    else if stage == 1 and curProfitInPts() >= tp //tp1123 //or tp
        stage := 2
    else if stage == 2 and curProfitInPts() >= tp2 //tp2123 //or tp2
        stage := 3
    stage

calcTrailingAmountLevel(points) =>
    var float level = na
    level := calcProfitTrgtPrice(points)
    if not na(level)
        if strategy.position_size > 0
            if not na(level[1])
                level := max(level[1], level)
            if not na(level)
                level := max(high, level)
        else if strategy.position_size < 0
            if not na(level[1])
                level := min(level[1], level)
            if not na(level)
                level := min(low, level)

calcTrailingOffsetLevel(points, offset) =>
    float result = na
    amountLevel = calcTrailingAmountLevel(points)
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        trailActiveDiff = amountLevel - calcProfitTrgtPrice(points)
        if trailActiveDiff > 0
            result := trailActiveDiff + calcProfitTrgtPrice(offset)
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        trailActiveDiff = calcProfitTrgtPrice(points) - amountLevel
        if trailActiveDiff > 0
            result := calcProfitTrgtPrice(offset) - trailActiveDiff
    result

float stopLevel = na
float trailOffsetLevel = na
float profitLevel = activateTrailingOnThirdStep ? calcTrailingAmountLevel(tp3123) : calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp3123)

// note: calcTrailingOffsetLevel uses calcTrailingAmountLevel and last one has a state (level).
//       therefor we needs calculate it on every bar for correct result.
//       if we inline it the Pine compiler give us warning "The function '***' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope."
trailOffsetLevelTmp = calcTrailingOffsetLevel(tp3123, tp2)  //(tp3123, tp2123)

// based on current stage set up exit
// note: we use same exit ids ("x") consciously, for MODIFY the exit's parameters


curStage = getCurrentStage()
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(sl) //stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(sl123)
    strategy.exit("x", loss = sl,  profit = tp3123, comment = "sl123 or tp3123") //strategy.exit("x", loss = sl123,  profit = tp3123, comment = "sl123 or tp3123")

    
else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(0)
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, profit = tp3123, comment = "breakeven or tp3123")

else if curStage == 3
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(-tp)  // stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(-tp1123)
    if activateTrailingOnThirdStep
        trailOffsetLevel := trailOffsetLevelTmp
        strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, trail_points = tp3123, trail_offset = tp3123-tp2, comment = "stop tp1 or trailing tp3 with offset tp2") //      strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, trail_points = tp3123, trail_offset = tp3123-tp2123, comment = "stop tp1 or trailing tp3 with offset tp2")
    
    else
        strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, profit = tp3123, comment = "tp1123 or tp3123")
else
    strategy.cancel("x")




    
// this is debug plots for visulalize TP & SL levels
plot(stopLevel, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.red)
plotshape(long and stopLevel, text='stop')
//plotshape(stopLevel, title = "stopLevel",                 style = shape.labelup,                  location = location.belowbar,         text = " stopLevel ",      color=bearcolor, textcolor=text, size=size.tiny)
alertcondition(stopLevel, title="LONG BUY_BINANCE_USDC-ETH_4000 ", message    = "LONG BUY_BINANCE_USDC-ETH_4000 {{exchange}}:{{ticker}}, price = {{close}}, volume = {{volume}} {{timenow}}")
 

plot(profitLevel, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.blue)
//plotshape(profitLevel, title = "profitLevel",                 style = shape.labelup,                  location = location.belowbar,         text = " profitLevel ",      color=bearcolor, textcolor=text, size=size.tiny)

plot(trailOffsetLevel, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.green)
//plotshape(trailOffsetLevel, title = "trailOffsetLevel",                 style = shape.labelup,                  location = location.belowbar,         text = " trailOffsetLevel ",      color=bearcolor, textcolor=text, size=size.tiny)
```

is it possibel to make this to a study insted so there can be set alarms for buy and stop

if any can help im willing to cast some coin after it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert this to a study, you need to replicate all those `strategy.x` built-in variables and functions. It can be done but not so easy.

However, `strategy.entry()`, `strategy.exit()` and `strategy.close()` function have `alert_message` property which you can use to trigger alerts.